# Is guava Maps.filterKeys same as going through stream to stream for the keys and looking up the map?

Tags: java, guava

Is doing Maps.filter same as looking to the collection and mapping for keys? Are both methods below the same? Do you reckon they are doing different things. Unit tests seemed fine but I want to double confirm.

Below, My filter approach is different, but I would like to confirm Maps.filterKeys is same as going through stream of keys and querying for data ?

```
 public List<Record> find(PrimaryKey key, Map<PrimaryKey, Record> data, Table table) {
        
        Set<PrimaryKey> primaryKeys = filterPrimaryKeys(data, key, table);
        return primaryKeys.stream()
                .map(data::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
    
   
    public List<Record> find(PrimaryKey key, Map<PrimaryKey, Record> data, Table table {
  
        Set<PrimaryKey> primaryKeys = filterPrimaryKeys(data, key, table);
        Map<PrimaryKey, Record> map = Maps.filterKeys(data, primaryKeys::contains);
        return Lists.newArrayList(map.values());
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it a view? What if you modify the `data` map and check what happens to the filtered map?

Comment: Not sure I get what you are asking?

Comment: Those methods do similar things but in different ways: the first method creates a _copy_ that won't change if the input `data` map is changed (usually a preferable way); the second method creates a _view_ with a backing map the modification methods delegate to, hence modifying the map returned by the `Maps.filterKeys` methods delegates the modifications to the backing map. This is the main difference.

Comment: However, in your case it is not "really 100% true", because both methods return new lists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're same. In both cases filtering / mapping operations are lazy but collecting / copying results to lists does the job right away (what @fluffy was trying to say in the comments). Using JDK methods should be preferable if it's just as readable as using third-party library.